# SQL Error (1111): Invalid use of group function in stored function mysql

Tags: mysql, function

i have a stored function as follows:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret decimal(18,2);
    DECLARE comp DECIMAL(18,2);
    DECLARE dia DECIMAL(18,2);
    DECLARE build DECIMAL(18,2);
    DECLARE sellPrice DECIMAL(18,2);
    DECLARE totalCost DECIMAL(18,2);
    DECLARE ssp DECIMAL(18,2);
    
    SET comp = IFNULL((SELECT sum(Cost/Rate) as TotalCost FROM VIEWProductComponent WHERE ProductID=prod),0);
    SET dia = IFNULL((SELECT sum(Weight*(CostPrice/Rate)) as TotalCost FROM tblProductDiamond pd LEFT JOIN VIEWDiamonds d on pd.DiamondId=d.StockCode WHERE ProductId=prod),0);
    SET build = IFNULL((SELECT Setting+Hallmark+Other1 as TotalCost FROM tblProductBuildCost where ProductId=prod),0);
    SET sellPrice = IFNULL((SELECT SellingPrice FROM tblProducts WHERE ProductId=prod),0);
    SET totalCost = comp + dia + build ;
    
    SET ret = totalCost;

RETURN 
    
    ret;
        
END
```

when i save this function and run a query as follows:
select fnProductBuildCost('3125011');
the first time i run this query on save of function i get back the correct number however if i run this query again i get an error:
SQL Error (1111): Invalid use of group function

can anyone help me why this is?

Comment: Provide: #1 - complete function code, not a middle part of it; #2 - complete CREATETABLE for all tables used in this function; #3 - complete query text in which you receive the error message in question. PS. Now I do not see any reason for shown error - everything looks like it is not related to your function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.